# Will parse notification works on china where google services are blocked?

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, real-time

As Google services are blocked in china will parse notifications work there. As i had heard Parse is using the GCM services only for sending the push notifications it will not work in china. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They won't work. I know people who bought a Galaxy in China and didn't even have the Google Play Store installed. They couldn't even download the Play Store. So the GCM are blocked, thus the Pushes won't work.

But there are alternatives out there! :-)

Comment: what services are for push notifications in china ?

Comment: There are some alternatives, I cannot recommend any of them, but a quick google search will give you a bunch of services that work in china! ;-)

Comment: At one point in history parse fully used their own push system and it worked. see https://parse.com/questions/will-parse-notification-works-on-china-where-google-services-are-blocked. The current docs state they can use it as a fallback so it still may work. I'm also trying to find a 100% answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried myself parse notification while I was traveling China for a week. And it worked fine!